# Como fazer uma concatenação entre uma string e outro tipo primitivo em um retorno de função?

Tags: c++

Estou fazendo uma função que retorna todas as informações da classe `ContaBanco.h`, como, o saldo atual, o dono, o tipo, etc, mas o compilador entende como uma soma e não como concatenação. Como posso resolver isso?

O código:

```
string statusConta() { 
    return "\nDono: " + getDono() + "\nAberta: " + getStatus() + "\nNumero: " + getNumConta() + "\nTipo: " + getTipo() + "\nSaldo: " + getSaldo();
}
```

Comment: Tentou utilizar a função `to_string`?

Answer (score 0):

Se vocês está usando um compilador que suporte C++14 você usar o sufixo "s" para indicar uma string.

Complementando: para tipos numéricos, usar to_string para converter para string. Supondo que getDono, getStatus, retornam valores numéricos, fiaria assim:

```
...
using namespace std::string_literals;
...
...
string statusConta()
  return "\nDono"s + to_string(getDono())...
```

Se você está usando um compilador que não suporte o sufixo "s" para strings, aí então você pode converter "xxx" (que é um ponteiro do tipo const char *) para string assim:

```
...
using namespace std::string_literals;
...
...
string statusConta()
  return string("\nDono") + to_string()getDono()...
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa to_string:

```
string statusConta() { 
   return "\nDono: " + to_string(getDono()) + "\nAberta: " + to_string(getStatus()) + "\nNumero: " + to_string(getNumConta()) + "\nTipo: " + to_string(getTipo()) + "\nSaldo: " + to_string(getSaldo());
}
```